# Why is the surface area of a sphere not given by this formula?

Tags: integration, geometry, surface-integrals

If we consider the equation of a circle:

$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$

Then I propose that the volume of a sphere of radius $R$ is given by the twice the summation of the circumferences of the circles between the origin and $x=R$ along the x axis, each circle having a radius equal to the value of y at that point in x.

Since

$$y={\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}$$

I derived the formula:

$$SA = 2\int^R_0{{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}}dx$$

However, evaluating this and using integration by substitution (using $x=R\sin(u)$ to find the integral, I obtained:

$$SA=2\pi R^2\left[\frac{\sin(2u)}{2}+\frac{u}{2}\right]^{\pi /2}_0$$

I have checked this multiple times and I can't seem to see what the problem is. If the problem is with the original proposition, *please could you explain why the proposition is incorrect*.

Comment: Here is a good source talking about surface areas of revolutions: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SurfaceArea.aspx. The surface area integral is done with the fustrum, not the cylinder. I'm not sure why the cylinder doesn't work, as I find, intuitively, it should.

Comment: The result of that integral should be the area of a semicircle. Why would you think it would have anything to do with a sphere?

Comment: @Kaynex The way I see it: both the cylinder and the fustrum methods are our *mathematical attempts* to model the real world. You cannot judge them unless from real life experience. And as the way they turn out, only the fustrum method provides the correct model that *fits the real world*.

Comment: @Kaynex see Ted Shifrin’s answer, below, and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4 for why cylinders won’t work.

Answer (score 10):

The key thing that's going on here is that you cannot compute the hypotenuse of a right triangle by taking one of the legs of the triangle. Consider the integral that gives arclength of a curve: You're adding up $\Delta s = \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$ when you chop the curve into pieces, *not* adding up $\Delta x$. When you're computing your integral, you're multiplying the length of the circle by $\Delta x$, whereas you should be multiplying it by $\Delta s$.

Comment: As you travel up from the equator the sphere curves away from the "infinitesimal" cylinders, so the ratio of the area of the cylinder to the area of a slice of the sphere  deviates significantly from 1.

Comment: Sure, but the flaw is there even for a cone, which doesn't "curve."

Comment: OK this makes sense but my issue with this is that when you calculate the volume of a sphere as opposed to the surface area, the approximation I use seems to give the correct result!

Comment: Yes, good point. Go back one dimension, again, and think about why adding up approximating rectangles gives the right answer for area under a curve. There, we need not use trapezoids (although trapezoids give a better numerical approximation, without limits).

Comment: Very good answer.

Answer (score 4):

One way to see your error is to note that the circumference of a circle is measured in (say) inches, and the surface area of a sphere is measured in square inches. It can’t work out that adding up inches gives you square inches. Your approach is not useless, however.

Each circle you’re using contributes an infinitesimally wide strip of the surface area - say you’re looking at the circle at $x=a$. The width of that strip supplies the second dimension that creates area from lengths.

In setting up the integral, imagine that the part of the surface area at $x=a$ is the band-like sliver of area between $x=a$ and $x=a+dx$, where $dx$ is infinitesimally small. The shape of that sliver over a tiny interval of $x$-values - in particular, its width - however, changes as $x$ varies. Specifically, the width is not the constant value $dx$ (which is what you are effectively assuming). Using $dx$ for the width happens to be a good approximation for the sliver-like bands you’re adding up near $x=a$. They’re shaped like the edge of a coin, but near $x=R$, the band is shaped very differently. It’s almost flattened into a washer shape, so the width is larger than $dx$. This observation is exactly why surface area calculations need to use $ds$ (the differential or infinitesimal change in arc) instead of $dx$. There is a helpful picture [here](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-formulas/derivation-formula-total-surface-area-sphere-integration).

Comment: In contrast to you first two paragraphs, he is adding up length (the perimeter of the circle) times length (dx).  The third is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$ SA = 2\int^R_0{{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}}dx $$

is not correct when summing up thin cone surface areas. Slant length is to be considered for each thin cone slice differential portion being integrated.

$$ ds= \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} $$

*Recall slant length $l$ is involved in slant area of cone in* $ \pi r l ,$ *not* $ \pi r H$. *Why do you attempt to make any difference here?*

Accordingly,

$$ SA = 2 \pi \int^R_0{{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}}ds. $$

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm presenting an opinion that's different from the other answers.

The other two answers seem to be trying to *mathematically* explain why one is supposed to integrate $\mathrm ds$ instead of $\mathrm dx$, but in my opinion, mathematics itself is unable to account for this, because they both are **mathematical  hypotheses to model the real world, and cannot be proved right or wrong within mathematics.**

Mathematics cannot tell whether a model is right or wrong, only **empirical evidence** can. Both the $\mathrm ds$ and the $\mathrm dx$ are such models. They are innocent until judged empirically.  And as the way they turn out, only the former fits the real world (the lateral surface area of a cone, so to speak).

To summarise, it makes little sense to judge a mathematical model only within mathematics. Only empirical evidence can tell us which models to accept and which to discard.

Comment: Can I copy this answer? This is something that I've seen many people simply don't get and then ask me something along the lines of "I applied X formula but the result is wrong" or "This is solid proof that math is wrong" . And it is *annoying*. If I show them this probably they'll stop annoying me.

Comment: @G-man Yes sure. Just use it as you please.

Comment: I was under the impression that the Q was about the mathematics of a mathematical model.

Comment: I totally disagree. We can compute the length of a non-horizontal line segment wrong and tell within mathematics that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @user254665 just as I said in my answer, I don't think the model can be mathematically justified.

Comment: @TedShifrin but do not forget that the concept of *length* is actually defined according to our empirical knowledge.

Comment: Going back to mathematics of the Greeks ... I don't buy your argument.

Comment: @TedShifrin never mind. After all it's only my opinion.

Comment: There's nothing here saying why cylinders can't be used as a surface. You're just saying "one works, one doesn't, therefore one works, one doesn't."

Comment: @Kaynex cylinders don't work because they don't fit the real world. If you apply cylinder approximation to calculate the lateral surface area of a cone you'll get a wrong result.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Man, if only I could answer all the math tests with "that's because it fits the real world"

Comment: @Kaynex ... It's a totally different matter. (But no problem if you're so inclined haha)

Comment: @Kaynex As for a test there are already existing standards or correct answers according to which to judge your performance, but as for a newly discovered mathematical model, the only standard is the real world.

Comment: @Kaynex Or, pretend you're taking a geometry exam in a strange civilisation where gravity is so strong as to distort the spacetime mesh, then if you write something like "the shortest path to connect two points is a segment", the professor probably won't be happy.

Comment: @TedShifrin For a counter-example where even extremely plausible intuition fails, see [Schwarz lantern](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/SchwarzLantern.shtml)

Comment: @Vim: I'm well aware. It is in one of the books I've written.